# Why Random.Range is overlapping button positions from the list in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, position

I have a list of UI Buttons and Vector2 for positions. I am using random.range to place buttons randomly every time i load them. But it never shows all 5 buttons at different positions. instead overlapping some of them. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
[SerializeField] List<Button> answersButtons = new List<Button>();
[SerializeField] List<Vector2> positions = new List<Vector2>();

void ShuffleAnswersList()
{             

    for (int i = 0; i < answersButtons.Count; i++)
    {              
       Vector2 tempPosition = 
       answersButtons[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;

       int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, positions.Count);

       answersButtons[i].transform.position = positions[randomIndex];
       answersButtons[randomIndex].GetComponent<RectTransform>().position 
       = tempPosition;

       Debug.Log(randomIndex);          
    }      

}

// shuffle positions
public void Shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
        int rnd = Random.Range(0, positions.Count);
        Vector2 tempGO = positions[rnd];
        positions[rnd] = positions[i];
        positions[i] = tempGO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, not sure where your Random.Range() function comes from, but there is a built-in Random in `System` that you can use to get random integers.
In this example the random is declared ahead and the Next() function is used to get a random number:

```
void Shuffle()
{
    System.Random random = new System.Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
        int rnd = random.Next(0, positions.Count);
        Vector2 tempGO = positions[rnd];
        positions[rnd] = positions[i];
        positions[i] = tempGO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to use any specific namespace to use random.next because it shows red line under it

Comment: what does the lightbulb say? should be in your project by default (edited the answer)

Comment: Random does not contain a definition for Next

Comment: @DenisSchaf : Unity3d has its own [`Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) class.

Comment: @Cid ok I get this but why is the default not working? @Sarita add the `System.` infront of the random

Comment: @Denis adding `System.` removed red line. Now its not overlapping  but still not showing all 5 buttons.

Comment: @Denis do you think it is maybe because of duplication in randomIndex? i tried `RemoveAt`  at the end `ShuffleAnswersList()` of but still doesn't show all 5 buttons

Comment: when you set the breakpoint in the forLoop do you see `rnd` beeing a new random value every time? Maybe all 5 buttons are there but always at the same position

Comment: @Denis Yes 2,2,4,2,2 these are random index values when i load a scene. which means it is taking 5 nos but duplicating and showing only one button

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this :

```
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, positions.Count);

answersButtons[i].transform.position = positions[randomIndex];
```

You *may* get the same value when you are randoming, that's why some button are overlapping.

You want to either :

- Shuffle the list of the position (what you did) and keep the same order for answers list
- Shuffle the list of answers and keep the same order for position

Try this instead :

```
void ShuffleAnswersList()
{             
    //  Notice this v--------------------v to avoid out of range exception
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count && i < answersButtons.Count; i++)
    {
// always use i ------V---------------------------------V
       answersButtons[i].transform.position = positions[i];
    }
}
```

Of course, make sure you call your method `Shuffle` first. This method need to be fixed, `Random.Range(min, max)` may return `max` (and provide a out of range exception)

```
// shuffle positions
public void Shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
// notice this -------------------------------------V
        int rnd = Random.Range(0, positions.Count - 1);
        Vector2 tempGO = positions[rnd];
        positions[rnd] = positions[i];
        positions[i] = tempGO;
    }
}
```

Comment: So is this happening because i am shuffling both the lists?  I am making changes as you told.so you mean `Shuffle` should return ~max~ value?

Comment: I changed both functions. Now only positions list elements are randomized and answerButtons list elements are in normal order 0-4. but not a single button is appearing on the screen.

Comment: Yes, `Random.Range` *could* return the max value, considering the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

Comment: Ah, I might have forgot something and removed too much things

Comment: can i possibly keep only `ShuffleAnswersList()` function and remove `Shuffle()` ? But then how do i remove duplicate random index? Please